CocoaPods compatibility issue with FBSDKCoreKit versions in Flutter project (iOS)
Description: I'm facing a compatibility issue with FBSDKCoreKit versions while integrating flutter_facebook_auth and facebook_app_events in my Flutter project, specifically on iOS. Here's the error message I'm encountering:
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In Podfile:
    facebook_app_events (from `.symlinks/plugins/facebook_app_events/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (~> 17.0)

    flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 6.0.4, which depends on
      FBSDKLoginKit (~> 16.3.1) was resolved to 16.3.1, which depends on
        FBSDKCoreKit (= 16.3.1)

I've tried updating flutter_facebook_auth, downgrading facebook_app_events, and manually adjusting the Podfile without success. Android integration is working fine. How can I resolve this compatibility issue and integrate both packages correctly in my Flutter iOS project?
Additional Information:-
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^6.0.4
  facebook_app_events: ^0.19.0


According to the facebook_app_events changelog, this version updates the package to be compatible with FBSDKCoreKit version 16.
However, in your case, FBSDKCoreKit is version 17.

To solve your issue just go to your project ios folder -> Podfile and change your platform :ios, from 17 to 16
